# Radius of convergence of $\frac{z}{1-z-z^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, fibonacci-numbers

So I want to find the radius of convergence of $\frac{z}{1-z-z^2}:=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}F_nz^n$ and also show that $F_n$ are the Fibonacci number.

$\underline{\text{My attempt}}$

To show that $F_n$ are the Fibonacci numbers is it enough to see that
\begin{align*}
\frac{z}{1-z-z^2}&=z(1-(z+z^2))^{-1}\\
&=z+z^2+2z^3+3z^4+5z^5+...
\end{align*}
where the coefficients seems to be the Fibonacci numbers?

To find the radius of convergence it is easy to see that $\alpha = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\beta =\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ are simple poles of $\frac{z}{1-z-z^2}$. So we can write $$\frac{z}{1-z-z^2}=\frac{z}{\sqrt{5}}\left( \frac{1}{z+\alpha}-\frac{1}{z+\beta}\right)$$however I'm not quite sure how to continue. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Convergence is only possible in a disk containing no pole.

Comment: So the radius of convergence is $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$?

Comment: $\dfrac{\sqrt5\color{red}-1}2$

Comment: It's $\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$ because we have a pole at $\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$?

Comment: Yes, and did you mean $\dfrac z{1-z-z^2}=z+z^2+...$?

Comment: Yes, don't know where $z^0$ came from... However is this enough to show that $F_n$ are the Fibonacci numbers or is there a better way? (using complex analysis)

Comment: @darkduck: the reference to the Fibonacci numbers is of no use. What matters is the position of the poles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$1-z-z^2=1+\dfrac14-\left(z+\dfrac12\right)^2=\dfrac54\left(1-\left(\dfrac{2z+1}{\sqrt5}\right)^2\right)$$

So we need $$\left|\dfrac{2z+1}{\sqrt5}\right|<1$$

Comment: Ah that's a very nice way to see it, thank you! Since you have not commented on my way to show that $F_n$ are the Fibonacci numbers does that mean it is correct or is there a better way (using complex analysis)?